# Why is the address size different? (0x206a10 - 0x104382e0)

Tags: go

http://play.golang.org/p/BgnHN-GikU

```
var p1 = new(int)
var p2 *int = new(int)
var p3 = 0
var p4 *int

func main() {
    fmt.Println(*p1, &p1, p1)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(*p2, &p2, p2)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(p3, &p3)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println(p4, &p4)
}
```

0 0x206a10 0x104382e0

0 0x206a14 0x104382f0

0 0x21ccc0

`<nil>` 0x206a18

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the address size what is different, it's the size (length) of the hexadecimal representation as you printed it.

All addresses you print on the Go Playground are 4 bytes, but if the first bytes (or bits) are zero, they are not printed.

Also if you take a closer look, addresses of your global vars have 6 hexa digits, pointers allocated and returned by `new()` have 8 hexa digits. This is because those `int`s (returned by `new()`) are allocated on the heap with bigger offset (and thus "bigger" memory address).

For example:

```
var i, j int32 = 123, 123000
fmt.Printf("%x %x\n", i, j)
```

Prints `7b 1e078` even though both numbers are 4 bytes long (32 bits). You may use a format string to add padding `0`s like this:

```
fmt.Printf("%08x %08x\n", i, j)
```

Which results in `0000007b 0001e078` but this will always pad to 8 digits even if `i` or `j` would be "less" than 4 bytes (e.g. `int16`), so this padding won't tell you if they are of different sizes.

Comment: Thank you, I see now :) PS maybe add the same example to your answer with printf maybe that does print the zero's if you have time.

Comment: @GertCuykens Yes, but format `%08p` and `%08x` will always pad to 8 hexa digits even if the argument is less than 4 bytes...